# How to create an array that will look up a string value in a sentence and return an int value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

My data is stored in Column F, the raw data looks like this:

**The Images- had poor pixel quality.**

What I want to do is to create an array formula that will look for my key word which is a string and convert that string keyword value to an int value.

```
Video= 1
Audio=2
Jpeg=3
Images=4
```

This is what I tried, but I just can't seem to work out the logic as it doesn't seem to recognize the order of my second array list.

```
lookup(F2,
       {"Video","Audio","Jpeg","Images"},
       {"1", "2","3","4"}
  )
```

Comment: Your posted image is not showing. However, an image is not usually helpful alone. Please share a link to your sheet (or to a copy of it).

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. Just to be clear, and please correct me if I am wrong. the cells in Column F consists strings. Each string includes one (and only one) of the following four words  `"Video","Audio","Jpeg","Images"`. You want to evaluate the string against the list of words, and substitute an integer value depending on the word list (`Video= 1 Audio=2 Jpeg=3 Images=4`). For example, a the string "The Images- had poor pixel quality." would be replaced by '4' because the string contains the word "Images. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the Docs Editors Help Topic [Google Sheet Arrayformula + IF + REGEXMATCH contains text within a range](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/61519652/google-sheet-arrayformula-if-regexmatch-contains-text-within-a-range?hl=en)

There are two options:

- a formula using an external list of search strings and corresponding values ("Mapping")
- a formula containing the various search strings and values (no Mapping).

**Mapping**

`=ArrayFormula(IFNA(vLOOKUP(regexextract(A2:A6,TEXTJOIN("|",1,Mapping!A2:A9)),Mapping!A2:B9,2,0),"Other"))`

**Not Mapped**
`=arrayformula(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A6,"Video"),1,IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A6,"Audio"),2,IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A6,"Jpeg"),3,IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A6,"Images"),4,"Other")))))`

---

**Sample data and results**

[image: sample]

**Mapping**

[image: map]